# Appending div from string which contains span does not render span as html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append to div another div which contains data

```
like

$("#messsages").append('<div class="message" id="' + message._id + '"><b>' + message.from + ': </b>' + message.body + '</div>');
```

where message.body is

```
message.body = replaceCoordinatesToClickableSpan(100, 200);

function replaceCoordinatesToClickableSpan(x, y) {
    return '  <span class="coordinates">(' + x + ',' + y + ')</span>  '; 
};
```

but when it renders I get result like (this is what I see in browser)

```
Guest: test <span class="coordinates">(8,9)</span>
```

( I need span to attach click event on spam, but here is rendered as text not like html tag)
Can anyone tell me what is a problem ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DT5YJ/1/ is this what you want as ouput

Comment: @user3127499 I need to replace coordinates with span in render before click and to every pair of coordinates / span attach callback for click

Comment: any fiddle please? looks like the full scene has not been shown.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DT5YJ/2/ checkout

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DT5YJ/3/ checkout and comment what exactly you want span is now appended cleanly to messages div just click the orange div